# Turn value to the left of NA to NA value for entire dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), 
                  b = c(NA,1,NA,1),
                  c = c(1,4,5,2), 
                  d = c(1,NA,NA,1))
```

```
  a  b c  d
1 1 NA 1  1
2 2  1 4 NA
3 3 NA 5 NA
4 4  1 2  1
```

I have columns `b` and `d` with either `NA` or `1`.

I have columns `a` and `c` with my values.

I want all the values to the left of `NA` values in `b` and `d` to be `NA`

So I want the following `df_1` but cant figure out how to get there:

```
  a  b  c  d
1 NA NA  1  1
2  2  1 NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA
4  4  1  2  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df[c(TRUE, FALSE)][is.na(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])] <- NA
df

   a  b  c  d
1 NA NA  1  1
2  2  1 NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA
4  4  1  2  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
myFun <- function(df){
  for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  if(is.na(df$b[i]))
    df$a[i]="NA"
  if(is.na(df$d[i]))
    df$c[i]="NA"
  }
  df
}
```

Output:

```
myFun(df)
   a  b  c  d
1 NA NA  1  1
2  2  1 NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA
4  4  1  2  1
```